# How to navigate between nested screens and prevent going back in React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

My desired app structure is that there will first be a `SplashScreen`, which then goes to the `LandingScreen`. From there the user either registers or logs in, he then goes to the `HomeScreen`. From there he can go to many other screens and come back to home.

When the user is in `LandingScreen`, he should not be able to go back to `SplashScreen`. When the user is in `HomeScreen`, he should not be able to go back to `LandingScreen` or any screen in `auth`.

- Is my navigator scheme correct for this type of app?
- How do I navigate from `LoginScreen` to `HomeScreen`?
- How do I prevent the user from going back as described above? I have tried `navigation.replace` for this.

This is my navigator:

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  splash: { screen: SplashScreen },
  auth: {
    screen: createStackNavigator({
      landing: { screen: LandingScreen },
      login: { screen: LoginScreen },
      register: { screen: RegisterScreen }
    })
  },
  main: {
    screen: createStackNavigator({
      home: { screen: HomeScreen },
      details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
      video: { screen: VideoScreen },
      search: { screen: SearchScreen }
    })
  }
},
{
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'splash',
  cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' },
});
```

Comment: Using `navigation.replace` works for you in the third point?

Comment: @JoseVf It works while moving from `SplashScreen` to `LandingScreen` but not from `LoginScreen` to `HomeScreen`.

Comment: @khateeb I have edited the answer below to put your own screens in, let me know if my answer has solved your problem, or if you need more informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two stackNavigators with a switchNavigator

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
const Auth = createStackNavigator(landing: { screen: LandingScreen },
                                  login: { screen: LoginScreen },
                                  register: { screen: RegisterScreen });
const main = createStackNavigator(home: { screen: HomeScreen },
                                  details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
                                  video: { screen: VideoScreen },
                                  search: { screen: SearchScreen });

export default createSwitchNavigator(
    {
    splash: SplashScreen,
    Auth,
    main,
    },
{
initialRouteName: 'splash',
}
);
```

The purpose of SwitchNavigator is to only ever show one screen at a time. By default, it does not handle back actions and it resets routes to their default state when you switch away.

Comment: I am implementing this and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Function via its screen based(which screen you want to go declare the navigate_screen_name ):

```
function_name = () => {
 this.props.navigation.navigate("navigate_screen_name");
 };
```

Function Call:

```
<onPress={this.function_name} />
```

Function via its history based(it goes to the previous screen):

```
func_name = () => {
 this.props.navigation.pop();
};
```

Function call:

```
<onPress={this.func_name} />
```